# CSS/HTML DIV needs to go across the screen in set position

Tags: html, css

I need a div filled with colour that goes across the screen behind the bottles like this:

[image]

Have tried too many times now...

Here is my html:

```css
  .panel {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: block;
}

.OriginalCollection {
  background: url(img/page_5_background.png);
}

.inner2 {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.centerwraper {
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

.centerdivcollections {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 1080px;
}

.allbottleswrap {
  display: flex;
}

.singlebottle {
  width: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .singlebottle {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.bottletextwraper {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.bottletext {
  padding: 0px 5px 0px 0px;
}

.titlebottle {
  width: 90%;
  .stripeee {
    background-color: #662d91;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-top: -45px;
  }
```

```html
<section class="panel OriginalCollection" data-section-name="OriginalCollection">
  <div class="inner2">
    <div class="centerwraper">
      <div class="centerdivcollections">
        <div>
          <img class="coltitle" src="img/original_header.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="allbottleswrap">
          <div class="bottletextwraper">
            <div>
              <img class="singlebottle" src="img/1Heisenberg.png" />
            </div>
            <div>
              <img class="titlebottle" src="Titles/Titles/Heisenberg.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="bottletext">
              <p>A top secret recipe that can only be described as the daddy of all day vapes. A fruity undertone and a cool crystal after sensation that will leave you wondering what it is... and wanting more.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="bottletextwraper">
            <div>
              <img class="singlebottle" src="img/2Pinkman.png" />
            </div>
            <div>
              <img class="titlebottle" src="Titles/Titles/Pinkman.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="bottletext">
              <p>The real MVP of the fruity flavours. Perfect for those looking for a one of a kind taste sensation. A true mouth-watering fruit explosion that your taste buds have been waiting for.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="bottletextwraper">
            <div>
              <img class="singlebottle" src="img/3BloodSukka.png" />
            </div>
            <div>
              <img class="titlebottle" src="Titles/Titles/BloodSukka.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="bottletext">
              <p>Packed with one hell of a bite. This flavour is crammed with sweet red cherries blended perfectly with fresh picked forest fruits. The fruity taste is then entangled beautifully with sweet eucalyptus and aniseed.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="stripeee">
          <br>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Everything is almost done as I want, except this stripe... If you want you can always go to [www.konceptxix.com](http://www.konceptxix.com) to see the actual site. It's probably an easy fix for someone who knows it well. Sorry for mess in the code, I'm doing my best...

UPDATE:
I can get this set to a position behind it, but it has to be responsive so it's the same on mobile etc...

Comment: The pink strip is the div you want behind the bottles? You haven't actually specified anything...

Comment: Or the black BG with the gradient in the middle

Comment: Yes, the stripe behind the bottles is what I actually want. Have a look at http://konceptxix.com/#SweetCollection

Comment: Do you know if the bottles already have the shadows at the base of the bottles? Otherwise, if it gets added, they won't look as if they're on the stripe

Comment: Scratch that, yes the shadows are on the images. Now, i did wish to have ago in the dev tools since you haven't reproduced your problem here in code (js fiddle/snippet) but I Can't scroll properly due to your scrolling plugins

Comment: I have disabled the plugin now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you want this to go all the way across the page? You'll want to use a pseudo element instead of a div, since it's just a decoration, and you can set the width to something impossibly wide to guarantee it fills the page - you already have overflow set to hidden on the sections, so it won't matter if it gets too wide. I used 150vw and set the left to -50vw, to guarantee that it's always at the far-left of the screen and goes all the way across.

From there, I needed to find a way to target the container for the images, that way I could position the pseudo element consistently as the image gets scaled down without worrying about overlapping the text. So I target the first bottle's first div, which is always the image, that way using different sized images doesn't cause weird double dividers. The result should be what you're looking for!

```
.bottletextwraper div:first-of-type{
 position: relative;
}
.bottletextwraper img{
 position: relative;
 z-index: 1;
}
.bottletextwraper:first-child div:first-of-type:after{
 content: '';
 display: block;
 width: 150vw;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 3%;
 left: -50vw;
 height: 15%;
 background: #662d91;
}
```

Comment: You are amazing... what can I say :D A lot of smart people around the world :)

Comment: Happy to help! Just keep coming up with unconventional design ideas, practice makes perfect!

Comment: Hymm, how do I make it a different colour for a different section?

Comment: You have a unique class per section, so just do something like .BakedCollection .bottletextwraper:first-child div:first-of-type:after{ background: red; }

Answer (score 0):

```
.bottletextwraper {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
}
.bottletextwraper::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: orange;
}
```

Try to add this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @will had the best answer to my question.

Comment: @BareFeet It's my pleasure :)

Answer (score 0):

Because the `stripee` is outside of `allbottletexwrapper` its harder to correctly set the `z-indexing`. If you can move it inside, you can do without z-index hacks. But anyway, here is what you can do:

```
 //set stripee to be relative and positioned (use your size units)
.stripeee {
 position: relative;
 top: -190px;
 z-index: 1;/*mind this... a bit hacky but... */
 }
```

And then style the bottles:

```
 .bottletextwraper {
   z-index: 5; /* use whatever number you consider safe according to the rest of page*/
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @will had the best answer to my question.